# Create a python function to delete a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

My code looks like this:

```
def col_add_drop(dataset, column_name, add = True, **kwargs):
    if add == True:
        column_values = kwargs.get('column_values', [])
        dataset[column_name] = column_values

    else:
        dataset = dataset.drop(column_name, axis=1)
```

When I try to add columns like

```
col_add_drop(dataset = df, column_name = 'income_cat_2', add = True, column_values = df['income_cat'])
```

this works fine, but when I try to delete columns by doing this:

```
col_add_drop(dataset = df, column_name = 'income_cat_2', add = False)
```

it does nothing, nor does it show any error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you modify it in the function by adding a column, pandas will add it to the original, but if you remove a column it just modifies the copy. You can do like this to solve this:

```
def col_add_drop(dataset, column_name, add = True, **kwargs):
    if add:
        column_values = kwargs.get('column_values', [])
        dataset[column_name] = column_values

    else:
        return dataset.drop(column_name, axis=1)
```

This way, you have to call the function like this:

```
df = col_add_drop(dataset = df, column_name = 'income_cat_2', add = False)
```

By the way, `if add == True:` is equivalent to `if add:` which looks cleaner.